Is Luke 4:8 enjoining to "worship and serve" or serve only

And Jesus answered and said unto him, Get thee behind me, Satan: for it is written, Thou shalt worship the Lord thy God, and him only shalt thou serve. - Luke 4:8 (KJV)

I have heard it asserted that this verse is not saying to worship God only but that it merely says to serve God only.  In other words the and between worship and serve acts more separative than copulative.
Is this assertion hermeneutically and linguistically valid?

Isn't the confusion simply caused by there not being an exact 1:1 mapping between the multiple meanings of the Greek and English words? And even more so when the meanings of the English words have changed since 1611. For instance, I call one of my neighbours Dorothy, but if I were ever to officially visit her at her work, in theory I would call her "Your Worship". There would be no implication of my having another god, or any other religious significance.

Jesus seems to paraphrase 1 Sam. 7:3

If you would return to the Lord with your whole heart, remove your
foreign gods and your Astartes, fix your hearts on the Lord, and serve
him alone, then the Lord will deliver you from the hand of the
Philistines.

If so, then although this scripture does not specifically say "worship God only," this idea is implied by the commandments to get rid of foreign deities and fix one's heart on the Lord. So ultimately, the proposition suggested in the OP is valid only by linguistic nitpicking. The teaching is to worship and serve God alone.

The text literally says:

5 And the Devil having brought him up to an high mountain, shewed to
him all the kingdoms of the world in a moment of time, 6 and the Devil
said to him, ‘To thee I will give all this authority, and their glory,
because to me it hath been delivered, and to whomsoever I will, I do
give it; 7 thou, then, if thou mayest bow before (προσκυνέω) me — all
shall be thine.’ 8 And Jesus answering him said, ‘Get thee behind me,
Adversary, for it hath been written, Thou shalt bow before (προσκυνέω)
the Lord thy God, and Him only thou shalt serve (λατρεύω).’

4352. proskuneó
Definition: To worship, to bow down, to prostrate oneself
Meaning: I go down on my knees to, do obeisance to, worship.
Word Origin: From πρός (pros, meaning "towards") and κυνέω (kuneó, meaning "to kiss")
Corresponding Greek / Hebrew Entries: - H7812 - שָׁחָה (shachah): To bow down, to prostrate oneself, often used in the context of worship.
3000. latreuó
Meaning: I serve, especially God, perhaps simply: I worship.
Word Origin: Derived from λάτρις (latris), meaning "a hired servant."
Corresponding Greek / Hebrew Entries: - H5647 עָבַד (avad): To work, serve; H8334 שָׁרַת (sharat): To minister, serve
Here are just a few examples of the use of bow down/worship and serve in the OT:

1 ‘And God speaketh all these words, saying, 2 I [am] Jehovah thy God,
who hath brought thee out of the land of Egypt, out of a house of
servants. 3 ‘Thou hast no other Gods before Me. 4 ‘Thou dost not make
to thyself a graven image, or any likeness which [is] in the heavens
above, or which [is] in the earth beneath, or which [is] in the waters
under the earth. 5 Thou dost not bow thyself to (שָׁחָה) them, nor
serve (עָבַד) them: for I, Jehovah thy God, [am] a zealous God,
charging iniquity of fathers on sons, on the third [generation], and
on the fourth, of those hating Me, 6 and doing kindness to thousands,
of those loving Me and keeping My commands. (Exodus 20)
20 ‘Lo, I am sending a messenger before thee to keep thee in the way,
and to bring thee in unto the place which I have prepared; 21 be
watchful because of his presence, and hearken to his voice, rebel not
against him, for he beareth not with your transgression, for My name
[is] in his heart; 22 for, if thou diligently hearken to his voice,
and hast done all that which I speak, then I have been at enmity with
thine enemies, and have distressed those distressing thee. 23 ‘For My
messenger goeth before thee, and hath brought thee in unto the
Amorite, and the Hittite, and the Perizzite, and the Canaanite, the
Hivite, and the Jebusite, and I have cut them off. 24 ‘Thou dost not
bow thyself to (שָׁחָה) their gods, nor serve (עָבַד) them, nor do according to their doings, but dost utterly devote them, and
thoroughly break their standing pillars. (Exodus 23)
19 And beware lest you raise your eyes to heaven, and when you see the
sun and the moon and the stars, all the host of heaven, you be drawn
away and bow down to them and serve them, things that the Lord
your God has allotted to all the peoples under the whole heaven.
(Deuteronomy 4)
8 “‘You shall not make for yourself a carved image, or any likeness of
anything that is in heaven above, or that is on the earth beneath, or
that is in the water under the earth. 9 You shall not bow down to
them or serve them; for I the Lord your God am a jealous God,
visiting the iniquity of the fathers on the children to the third and
fourth generation of those who hate me, 10 but showing steadfast love
to thousands of those who love me and keep my commandments.
(Deuteronomy 5)
18 but remember that the Lord your God gives you the power to gain
wealth, in order to confirm his covenant he swore to your ancestors,
as it is today. 19 If you ever forget the Lord your God and follow
other gods to serve them and bow in worship to them, I testify
against you today that you will certainly perish. 20 Like the nations
the Lord is about to destroy before you, you will perish if you do not
obey the Lord your God. (Deuteronomy 8)
13 If, then, you truly listen to my commandments which I give you
today, loving and serving the Lord, your God, with your whole heart
and your whole being, 14 I will give the seasonal rain to your land,
the early rain and the late rain, that you may have your grain, wine
and oil to gather in; 15 and I will bring forth grass in your fields
for your animals. Thus you may eat and be satisfied. 16 But be careful
lest your heart be so lured away that you serve other gods and
bow down to them. 17 For then the anger of the Lord will flare up against you and he will close up the heavens, so that no rain will
fall, and the soil will not yield its crops, and you will soon perish
from the good land the Lord is giving you. (Deuteronomy 11)
2 “If a man or woman among you in one of your towns that the Lord your
God will give you is discovered doing evil in the sight of the Lord
your God and violating his covenant 3 and has gone to serve other
gods by bowing in worship to the sun, moon, or all the stars in
the sky — which I have forbidden 4 and if you are told or hear about
it, then investigate it thoroughly. If the report turns out to be true
that this detestable act has been done in Israel, 5 you are to bring
out to your city gates that man or woman who has done this evil thing
and stone them to death. (Deuteronomy 17)
22 “Future generations of your children who follow you and the
foreigner who comes from a distant country will see the plagues of
that land and the sicknesses the Lord has inflicted on it. 23 All its
soil will be a burning waste of sulfur and salt, unsown, producing
nothing, with no plant growing on it, just like the fall of Sodom and
Gomorrah, Admah and Zeboiim, which the Lord demolished in his fierce
anger. 24 All the nations will ask, ‘Why has the Lord done this to
this land? Why this intense outburst of anger? ’ 25 Then people will
answer, ‘It is because they abandoned the covenant of the Lord, the
God of their ancestors, which he had made with them when he brought
them out of the land of Egypt. 26 They began to serve other gods,
bowing in worship to gods they had not known — gods that the Lord had not permitted them to worship. 27 Therefore the Lord’s anger
burned against this land, and he brought every curse written in this
book on it. 28 The Lord uprooted them from their land in his anger,
rage, and intense wrath, and threw them into another land where they
are today.’ (Deuteronomy 29)
15 See, today I have set before you life and prosperity, death and
adversity. 16 For I am commanding you today to love the Lord your God,
to walk in his ways, and to keep his commands, statutes, and
ordinances, so that you may live and multiply, and the Lord your God
may bless you in the land you are entering to possess. 17 But if your
heart turns away and you do not listen and you are led astray to bow
in worship to other gods and serve them, 18 I tell you today
that you will certainly perish and will not prolong your days in the
land you are entering to possess across the Jordan. 19 I call heaven
and earth as witnesses against you today that I have set before you
life and death, blessing and curse. Choose lifea so that you and your
descendants may live, 20 love the Lord your God, obey him, and remain
faithful to him. For he is your life, and he will prolong your days as
you live in the land the Lord swore to give to your ancestorsa
Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob.” (Deuteronomy 30)

They are used together quite often, aren't they. Especially in the Fifth Book of Moses. We can easily call the phrase "do not bow to other gods and serve them" Deuteronomic. Together with the call to listen and to love God, it is the most often repeated sentence in Deuteronomy. Often times both words seem to be synonyms, where bowing down/worship (in religious context), is the simplest and the most outwardly way of serving.

This answer conveniently ignores all of the scriptures that direct "worship" (προσκυνέω) towards men - or even simultaneously towards men and God as in 1 Chronicles 29:20

I don't exactly know what you mean. Are you suggesting that David was worshipped by the people?

20Then David said to all the assembly, “Now bless (praise, thank) the LORD your God.” And all the assembly blessed the LORD, the God of their fathers, and bowed down and honored the LORD and the king [as His earthly representative]. (Amplified Bible)

That word for bowed down is the same one translated as worship in Luke 4:8, so yes - they worshipped him along with God. See my answer for several examples of humans receiving worship.

It is a virtual impossibility to interpret the verse, the way you do, in the context of the Hebrew culture.

The Jews are fully aware that the word which we errantly translate as “worship” is applied to both men and to God. Moses likewise “worshiped” his father-in-law, and Elisha was “worshiped” when he succeeded Elijah. The real problem is that “worship” isn’t a biblical term. Translators have selectively used that word in place of what is actually written - in this case “to bow down”

That is what I stated in my post. That proskuneó and shachah literally mean to bow down. It can be an act of veneration of a deity (true or false). Or a sign of respect for another person. One has a religious context while the other has not. The word worship in the past was used the same way. Unfortunately, the meaning was narrowed down to only the religious context. So when people read from the KJV, they don't know the wider definition of the word from the past.

Merriam-Webster's definition of worship today:
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/worship

Webster's definition of worship in 1828:
https://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/worship


Excellence of character; dignity; worth; worthiness.
A title of honor, used in addresses to certain magistrates and other of respectable character.
A term of ironical respect.
Chiefly and eminently, the act of paying divine honors to the Supreme Being; or the reverence and homage paid to him in religious exercises, consisting in adoration, confession, prayer, thanksgiving and the like.
The homage paid to idols or false gods by pagans; as the worship or Isis.
Honor; respect; civil deference.
Idolatry of lovers; obsequious or submissive respect.


Worship is an English word, it is not a Hebrew or Greek word - nor is there is a direct correspondence between it and any single Hebrew or Greek word. It is an abstract concept that we have come to use in place of many distinct terms in the Hebrew and Greek - and in doing so they have injected along with it this concept of veneration specific to deity. That idea is not present in the Hebrew or the Greek - as witnessed by the fact that the terms in question are readily applied to both men and to God, and even within the exact same context like in 1 Chronicles 29:20.

And you did not address how words like proskuneo are used in scripture in your OP, which is why you were unaware that it is applied to both God and to men. You post only addresses a very small subset of the scriptures - which leads you to the absolutely erroneous conclusion that worship and service and synonymous. You are simply wrong, and you are digging in your heels rather than look how these biblical terms are actually used in the scriptures.

@RyanPierceWilliams I believe he is saying that service to God flows from worship of God; not that they are synonymous.

@MikeBorden and I’m saying that conflating “worship” with service is fundamentally erroneous; scripture only speaks of serving God alone, not of “worshiping” him alone - and there are many counter-examples in the scriptures. Using “worship” with this extra sense of belonging to God alone is contradictory to the underlying terms actually found in the Hebrew and Greek

@RyanPierceWilliams If one flows from the other, where is the conflation?  That would be like conflating an apple with an apple tree.  And are you saying that there is no distinction to be made in bowing down to a human dignitary and bowing down to God?  I don't think anyone is suggesting this in their answers.

@MikeBorden one doesn’t flow from the other; they are two distinct actions. Serving God means just that: carrying out his will, doing what he commands. Bowing down is a way of honoring God. Moses bowed down to his father-in-law; that doesn’t mean he served him.

@RyanPierceWilliams Can you really serve God if you haven't first bowed to Him (in Spirit and Truth)?  The OT is filled with those whose "service" is rejected because it is hollow; empty of worship.  See Rev. 19:10 and 22:9 where John bows to an angel and the angel says "Don't bow to [worship] me since I am your fellow-servant [of God]; bow to  [worship] God".  Worship of God and service to God are both distinct and inextricably linked.  One cannot serve God acceptably without worshiping Him as God, otherwise whom or what is being obeyed in service?

@MikeBorden The issue of the spirit in which an action is done is an entirely different concern from the word used to communicate that action in scripture. The verb “to bow down” remains the same irregardless of who performs the action and irregardless of whom the action is directed.

@RyanPierceWilliams Strictly speaking the verb necessitates a change in body posture.  However, the verb has both a literal and a figurative application of "bow down".  Can one "bow down" before God (as worship) in Spirit and Truth without an actual change in body posture?

@MikeBorden There is no "worship" in scripture; that wasn't a term in Hebrew or Greek and there is no spiritual sense elucidated in scripture for "bowing down" by which you can argue that it is within the spectrum of meaning for the term. And no, you cannot bow down without bowing down. When it says to bow down in Spirit and in Truth, it is referring to the spirit by which the action is performed - not speaking of NOT doing that action.

@Ryan Pierce Williams  Why are you still ranting about the meaning of proskuneo/shachah? We know it means to bow down. What you missed, however, is the fact that when proskuneo/shachah and latreuo/avad are used together, the phrase is always idiomatic and has cultic meaning.

Idiomatic - (of a group of words) having a particular meaning that is different from the meanings of each word considered separately.

No, you have posited that it is an idiomatic expression- not substantiated it. Indeed, you don’t seem to understand what an idiomatic phrase is: an expression that conveys a meaning greater than the sum of its parts. You would need to examine Jewish usage and interpretation of that phrase and/or koine usage of that phrase at the time of Christ to establish any such idiomatic usage. Finding multiple cases of it in scripture is insufficient- particularly when the meaning of the phrase is clear as written.

@RyanPierceWilliams So, one can honor God with the lips while the heart is far from Him but one cannot bow down without bowing down?  I heartily disagree as one who did so for many, many years.

@MikeBorden you are only fooling yourself. If you don’t bow down then you aren’t bowing down. It’s as simple as that. You speak non-sense

@RyanPierceWilliams Did the thief on the cross bow down or not?

@MikeBorden no; scripture doesn’t say that he did at any rate

@RyanPierceWilliams I would say that one did and one didn't;  neither with a body posture (being all crucified and all).

@MikeBorden You can make up whatever you want; you can’t substantiate it

Tom Wadsworth wrote his PhD thesis on this subject in 2022, titled A WORSHIP SERVICE OR AN ASSEMBLY: AN INVESTIGATION OF THE TERMINOLOGY USED TO DESCRIBE CHURCH MEETINGS IN THE NEW TESTAMENT.
The abstract reads

This project sought to discover why NT writers did not describe
Christian assemblies as “worship.” The project’s methodology analyzed
fifteen NT assembly passages and the five NT Greek words that are
translated as “worship.” The study concluded that NT assemblies were
primarily for mutual edification. Most assembly activities were
horizontally oriented toward one another, although a few events were
vertically oriented toward God. The Greek “worship” words largely
pertained to temple activities, and the NT teaches that the sacrifice
of Christ nullifies the temple and its ritual practices. Consequently,
these Greek words did not apply to NT Christian meetings.

He later goes on to describe modern usage of the word, "worship."

Today, attending a weekly assembly is widely referred to as “going to
worship.” Church buildings are often called “houses of worship.”
Church meetings are often known as “worship services.” These meetings
often follow a prescribed “order of worship” and are often led by a
worship pastor, a worship leader, or a worship team.

But how did Jesus use the term, προσκυνέω (proskuneó)? In John 4:24 (ESV), we read his reply to the Samaritan woman:

“God is spirit, and those who worship him must worship in spirit and
truth.”

However, what’s the context?
The Samaritan woman asks Jesus the question of whether one should worship God on Mount Gerizim or in the Temple. Jesus evades her question, instead directing her to look to a future where worship is (1) not performed at a specific location, (2) does not consist of a liturgy, but (3) comprises solely of two elements: spirit and truth.
Romans 12:1 tells us that our reasonable/logical spiritual service (the word is not not “worship” which conflates or extrapolates SG 2999 latreia with SG 4352 proskuneó) consists of offering our bodies as a living sacrifice to God.
To answer the posted question, the fact that the letters to the assemblies of Christians in the New Testament did not mention worship (proskuneó), but only serving each other and “bearing fruit” indicates that the two concepts, worship and serving, are separate.
Addendum to Worship versus Serving
In context with the cultures of the time, a person bowing, kneeling, or prostrating themselves before a king was demonstrating submission to that king. Also, note that in Islam, which means surrender or submission in Arabic, Muslims are expected to pray five times a day along with two prostrations.
Jesus told the following parable to the religious leaders who challenged him:

“What do you think? A man had two sons. And he went to the first and
said, ‘Son, go and work in the vineyard today.’ And he answered, ‘I
will not,’ but afterward he changed his mind and went. And he went to
the other son and said the same. And he answered, ‘I go, sir,’ but did
not go. Which of the two did the will of his father?” They said, “The
first.” Jesus said to them, “Truly, I say to you, the tax collectors
and the prostitutes go into the kingdom of God before you. – Matthew
21:28-31 ESV

Notice that the first son did not submit to his father, but later served him. The second son did submit to his father but didn’t serve him. Jesus concluded that the tax collectors and prostitutes were like the first son, while the religious leaders were like the second son.
Many churches reject “works-based salvation” so strongly that they don’t even mention any works at all. Instead, this type of church expects the following:

Weekly attendance (aka “worship service”)
Offerings of money (aka “sacrificial giving”)
Recruitment of new attendees ("the great commission"?)
Agreement with church distinctives and doctrines (aka "purity")

Let’s examine three passages in the final chapter of Paul’s letter to Titus pertaining to salvation and works:

But when the goodness and loving kindness of God our Savior appeared,
he saved us, not because of works done by us in righteousness, but
according to his own mercy, by the washing of regeneration and renewal
of the Holy Spirit. – Titus 3:4,5 ESV
The saying is trustworthy, and I want you to insist on these things,
so that those who have believed in God may be careful to devote
themselves to good works. These things are excellent and profitable
for people. – Titus 3:5 ESV
And let our people learn to devote themselves to good works, so as to
help cases of urgent need, and not be unfruitful. – Titus 3:14 ESV

In the last quote, Paul links good works with fruitfulness. In other letters, Paul also provides lists of "the fruit of the Spirit."
Worship is not mentioned in Paul’s letter, but good works are expected as the outcome of our faith. However, in the Gospels of Matthew and Luke, Jesus does teach worship as part of “worship in spirit and truth” (John 4:24) as follows:

Pray then like this: “Our Father in heaven, hallowed be your name.
Your kingdom come, your will be done, on earth as it is in heaven. –
Matthew 6:9,10 ESV

The word "father" specifies a relationship, the word "hallowed" shows respect and preeminence, and the word "your" expresses precedence over our own wills.
Hope this helps.

So, are you saying that in Luke 4:8 Jesus is not saying to worship only God but he is saying to serve only God?

+1 "the two concepts, worship and serving, are separate."

@Mike, I'm still internalizing what I've been reading over the last few days. But I'll add an addendum to clarify what the New Testament seems to be telling us. I'm most certainly not trying to fit scripture into doctrine, which could rightfully be termed biazogesis. ;-)

@MikeBorden, worship God only, but that worship of God can also include his representatives, namely the King of kings. Wen we worship before Christ, we are not worshipping him as God, but worshipping God through his representative by honoring the one God appoints.

@OneGodOneLord Agreed.  It is the nature of the King of kings, whom God has commanded the angels to worship, that is most crucial.

There is a reason why weekly Christian gatherings are called "Services of Worship". The events that take place - prayer, singing praise, exposition of the Bible, partaking of bread & wine, baptism, etc - are ALL part of Christian worship of the one God.
They gather to carry out a Service of Worship.
The "Order of Service" (usually printed out and given to participants, or shown on an overhead screen) details how worship will proceed. Right from the start of the Service, to its conclusion (a closing prayer and benediction), God is being worshipped.
This means that serving God (as far as Christians are concerned) includes worship of God. To worship God is to serve him.
In the context of Luke 8:4, Jesus was refusing to bow down to serve Satan in (or, as) an act of worship.
This means that the answer to the question is that there is no linguistic or hermeneutic problem. Worship given is an act of service to the one being worshipped.
EDIT in view of new answers generating many comments: It is unarguable that not every gathering of Christians to worship God is “worship in spirit and in truth” (John 4:23) where Jesus said “true worshippers” do that. Therefore, there are false would-be-worshippers whose services of worship are unacceptable to God. Yet, even in such meetings, two or three may be in the midst, whose worship IS acceptable to God. In the first century, where the Spirit of God moved in their gatherings, non-Christians who came in would exclaim that “God is truly in your midst” (1 Corinthians 14:24-25).
Over the centuries to this very day highly offensive, God-dishonouring things are done and said in some congregational gatherings. But, irrespective of location, individual Christians render their service of worship acceptably to God, whether privately or in congregational gatherings:

“By [Jesus] therefore let us offer the sacrifice of praise to God
continually, that is, the fruit of our lips giving thanks to his name.
But to do good and to communicate forget not: for with such sacrifices
God is well pleased.” Hebrews 13:15-16 A.V.

It is not linguistics that determine the answer to the question, but the heart conditions of those rendering their acts, and services of worship to God, whether privately, or alongside others.

You are correct that modern churches conflate "service" and "worship" - but doing so is bad theology that fails to account for the distinct biblical usage of these terms.

Jesus is referring to the OT. There is a commandment both to serve God and there is a commandment to not create idols or to serve or “worship” these- but at no point in the OT is “worship” (= bowing down = προσκυνέω) said to belong to God only. There is also a commandment to not have any other gods before him, or to be led astray to serve them.
Note that for the Greek of the OT I am using the Septuigant (LXX).
Monotheism: No other gods

Exodus 20:3 “You shall have no other gods before Me.

Iconoclasm: Do not create or serve (λατρεύσῃς) or worship (προσκυνήσεις) idols

Exodus 20:4-6 You shall not make for yourself an idol, or any likeness of what is in heaven above or on the earth beneath, or in the water under the earth. 5 You shall not worship them nor serve them; for I, the Lord your God, am a jealous God, inflicting the punishment of the fathers on the children, on the third and the fourth generations of those who hate Me, 6 but showing favor to thousands, to those who love Me and keep My commandments.

Serve (λατρεύειν) God with all you have

Deuteronomy 10:12
“And now, Israel, what does the Lord your God require of you, but to fear the Lord your God, to walk in all His ways and love Him, and to serve the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul,

Put away other gods and serve (λατρεύσατε) the Lord (alone)

Joshua 24:14-15 “Now, therefore, [a]fear the Lord and serve Him in sincerity and [b]truth; and do away with the gods which your fathers served beyond the Euphrates River and in Egypt, and serve the Lord. 15 But if it is disagreeable in your sight to serve the Lord, choose for yourselves today whom you will serve: whether the gods which your fathers served, which were beyond the Euphrates River, or the gods of the Amorites in whose land you are living; but as for me and my house, we will serve the Lord.”


1 Samuel 7:3 Then Samuel spoke to all the house of Israel, saying, “If you are returning to the Lord with all your heart, then remove the foreign gods and the Ashtaroth from among you, and direct your hearts to the Lord and serve Him alone; and He will save you from the hand of the Philistines.”


1 Samuel 12:24 Only fear the Lord and serve Him in truth with all your heart; for consider what great things He has done for you.


2 Kings 17:35 The Lord made a covenant with them and commanded them, saying, “You shall not fear other gods, nor bow down to them, nor serve them, nor sacrifice to them.

There are plenty more such references- but none of them say to worship (προσκυνέω = bow down to) God alone. To the contrary, there are numerous instances in the OT where men “worship” (προσκυνέω) other men. For example, Moses “worshiped” his father-in-law.

Exodus 18:7 Then Moses went out to meet his father-in-law, and he bowed down (προσεκύνησεν) and kissed him; and they asked each other about their welfare, and went into the tent.

Such an act was a common enough act back when as a sign of both deference and respect; a way of honoring another. This is perfectly inline with the commandments, which even command us to honor our parents (or father-in-law in this case).
Likewise, men bowed down to human kings and before prophets in the OT and it is never rebuked.

2 Kings 2:15 Now when the sons of the prophets who were at Jericho opposite him saw him, they said, “The spirit of Elijah has settled on Elisha.” And they came to meet him and bowed down (προσεκύνησαν) to the ground before him.


1 Chronicles 29:20 Then David said to all the assembly, “Now bless the Lord your God.” And all the assembly blessed the Lord, the God of their fathers, and bowed down (προσεκύνησαν) and paid homage to the Lord and the king.

So then, while there is a commandment against “worshiping” idols - the work of one’s hands - there is no commandment against “worshiping” men nor a commandment to reserve "worship" for God alone. To the contrary, David is even seen above being bowed down to (προσεκύνησαν) and paid homage alongside God!!!
Contextually, therefore, it would make no sense for Christ to be saying that “worship” is reserved for God alone. That is not written anywhere in the OT.
Furthermore, the underlying Greek does not state to worship God alone either in Luke 4:8; the word "alone" (μόνῳ) being an adjective describing “him” (αὐτῷ) which is the dative object receiving the action “serve” (λατρεύσεις).
The act of “worship” (προσκυνήσεις) has its own object in the accusative = “the Lord your God” (Κύριον τὸν θεόν σου). See https://biblehub.com/text/luke/4-8.htm

This answer addresses the central question here - the grammar of the verse.  As commonly translated, the statement of Jesus in Luke 4:8 appears to be two clauses (eg, ESV)

And Jesus answered him, “It is written, “‘You shall worship the Lord
your God, and him only shall you serve.’”

However, such translation ignore some important features of the Greek:

"only" = μόνῳ is an ADJECTIVE and not an adverb; thus, "only" says something about a noun and not a verb.  In this instance it modifies the pronoun "Him".
"Him only" is dative and not nominative
"Him only", because it is dative, appears to act as an appositional phrase emphasizing "God".

Thus, based on the Greek, we may translate Luke 4:8 as:

And Jesus answered him, "You shall worship the Lord your God, and Him
alone, you shall serve."

Or, less ambiguously:

And Jesus answered, "You shall worship and serve the Lord your God and
Him alone.

Thus, "Him alone" refers to God, the One who is to be worshiped and served.

Overall good answer. However, your “less ambiguous” phrasing is incorrect.. The dative “him only” is the object of the verb “serve” whereas “(the) Lord your God” in the accusative is the object of the verb “worship.” Combining those two as the common object of both verbs is incorrect.

@RyanPierceWilliams - I would beg to differ precisely because removing the appositional phrase would make the sentence read, "It is written, you shall worship the Lord your God and you shall serve."  This simply means that "serve" is placed after the object - quite common in Greek.

It's not an appositional phrase - λατρευω takes its object in the dative case

the subject of both verbs is "you" - which you can determine from how the verbs are conjugated. The object of worship is in the accusative (the Lord your God)

you also mentioned the nominative case - which is what the subject would be in. The object is in the accusative for "worship" = the Lord your God.

you are simply wrong here. Anyone who has taken even a single semester of Greek can clearly see that Κύριον τὸν Θεόν is in the accusative, not the nominative. Furthermore, you would get a very different translation if it were in the nominative - something along the lines of "You, the Lord your God, shall bow down and serve him alone"

@RyanPierceWilliams - woops - my apology - you are correct - Κύριον τὸν Θεόν is indeed accusative.

Good discussion and thank you, @Dottard, for noting the correction . . . have you already corrected your answer?

@Dieter - the answer above did not have this error.

@Dieter he has still not corrected the real issue - combining the two distinct objects of each of the verbs into one in his "less ambiguous" translation, which is erroneous

An explanation would be helpful for understanding the issue, even if you're not in full agreement.

In my reflection, Luke 4:8, in which Jesus responds to Satan's temptation, is a crucial verse for understanding the believer's relationship with worship and service to God. In saying "You shall worship the Lord your God and serve him alone", this verse raises an important question: does it enjoin "reducing the word to serve only", or does it also enjoin worship? This study explores this question through different dimensions of the text.
Luke 4:8 is one of Jesus' temptations in the desert, as described in the three Synoptic Gospels (Matthew 4:10 and Mark 1:13). This temptation underlines Jesus' authority in the face of Satan, and defines their conceptual relationship to the notions of worship and service. The overall context of the passage is that Jesus must affirm his commitment to God while rejecting Satan's offers of authority and material power.
Etymologically, the term used in Luke 4:8 for "worship" is the Greek verb "προσκυνέω" (proskyneō), which literally means "to prostrate oneself" or "to pay homage". In the Jewish context, worship implies recognition of God's sovereignty. The word "serve" comes from the Greek verb "λατρεύω" (latreuo), which refers to the idea of serving in a religious sense, often used in the context of sacrifices or worship. Thus, the etymology of these terms underlines that worship and service are distinct yet intimately linked actions in the biblical tradition.
An exegetical and hermeneutical analysis reveals that, in the context of Luke 4:8, Jesus quotes Deuteronomy 6:13: "You shall fear the Lord your God; it is he whom you shall worship, and by his name you shall take oaths." This quotation underlines the importance of the two actions - worship and service - as complementary expressions of man's relationship with God. The structure of the verse emphasizes that worship precedes service, implying that service is a natural consequence of genuine worship.
The hermeneutical interpretation of Luke 4:8 can be extended to the way believers live out their faith today. In the Christian tradition, worshipping God is often understood not only as an act of praise, but also as a way of living one's life in accordance with His commandments. This implies that service to God (and to others) flows from worship. Thus, Jesus' exhortation to worship and serve underlines that the two dimensions cannot be separated in the life of the believer.
As far as textual criticism is concerned, variations in early manuscripts show some differences in the wording of Luke 4:8, but the main idea of adoring and serving seems to be well attested. Unabridged versions of the text, such as Codex Vaticanus and Codex Sinaiticus, support the reading that includes both verbs "adore" and "serve". This supports the idea that Jesus' original message implied an integrative relationship between these two aspects of faith.
So Luke 4:8 clearly enjoins us not only to serve, but to adore and serve the Lord. This double exhortation underlines the importance of acknowledging God's sovereignty while following His ways through service. By integrating worship and service, the verse calls for a life full of devotion and commitment to God, thus laying a solid foundation for the Christian life. Understanding this verse helps us realize that worship and service are two parts of a dynamic and integral relationship with God.
Thank you

"In the Jewish context, worship implies recognition of God's sovereignty" this is false. "worship" aka bowing down is done in the OT to both men and to God, even simultaneously as in 1 Chronicles 29:20. It is English translators who have introduced this modern conception of worship which isn't found in the original biblical languages. And they selectively translate it as worship rather than always translate προσκυνέω as worship (again, as seen in 1 Chronicles 29:20 if you look at a translation of the Septuigant)

@JEREMIETCHINDEBE - Jesus said, "I came NOT to be served, but to serve."
